# Why the labels are not arranged properly in `stars()` in R?

Tags: r, graphics, r-markdown

I am using following function to generate `stars()`, one the visualization technique for multivariate data.

```
library(randomNames)
set.seed(3)
Name = randomNames(50, which.names = 'first')
height = sample(160:180, 50, replace = TRUE)
weight = sample(45:85, 50, replace = TRUE)
tumour_size = runif(50, 0,1)
df = data.frame(Name, height, weight, tumour_size, rnorm(50, 10,3))

stars(df,labels = Name)
```

But, I get the output like this:

[image]

### How to align the names exactly below the stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option `flip.labels=FALSE`.

```
stars(df, labels = Name, flip.labels = FALSE)
```

***Result***

[image]